# How to use makefiles on Windows

Tags: windows, make, makefile

I have a LaTeX project using make files for compilation and want to write the texts on Windows using Kile.

I had a quick look on google but only really came up with [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) the last version of which dates back to 2006. Maybe it is just incredibly well done and stable, but I would still like to know:

**Which are the alternatives (if any) to use makefiles on Windows?**

In the ideal case I would like to configure the tool into Kile (which is running on Windows, yes) and run it from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest is to use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and run linux command.
Another way is to use nmake command provided by the windows SDK but, in this case, you have to edit some part of the makefile.
I suggest the first solution.
Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great solution as it also uses a repository (the thing I miss most on Windows).

Comment: I also added the cygwin binaries (C:\cygwin\bin per default) to my PATH system variable. After restarting Kile and configuring a new `make` command as a build tool I was able to use make from Kile.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is [**MinGW**](http://www.mingw.org/), which can compile to a native Win32 program.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022 there are some changes and at least one option not covered in earlier answers. First, to note, the Make for Windows tool linked in the original post is now 16 years out of date (v3.81, the latest GNU Make version is v4.3)

Several options are mentioned in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows) (reproduced below)

> `make` is a GNU command so the only way you can get it on Windows is
> installing a Windows version like the one provided by [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html).
> Anyway, there are several options for getting that:
>
> 1. The most simple choice is using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install). First you need to install this package manager. Once installed you simlpy need to
>    install `make` (you may need to run it in an elevated/admin command
>    prompt) :
>
>    ```
>    choco install make
>    ```
> 2. Other recommended option is [installing a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL/WSL2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), so you'll have a Linux distribution of your
>    choice embedded in Windows 10 where you'll be able to install `make`,
>    `gcc`and all the tools you need to build C programs.
> 3. For older Windows versions (MS Windows 2000 / XP / 2003 / Vista / 2008 / 7 with msvcrt.dll) you can use [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html).
>
> An outdated alternative was [MinGw](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingw.html), but the project seems to be
> abandoned so it's better to go for one of the previous choices.

The version available through Chocolatey is likely to be the best behaved option if you want to integrate into other windows applications' workflows, as it sets up appropriate path entries. I've used this successfully with VS Code, whereas the WSL solution didn't play nice with filesystem paths in the Makefile extension.

If setting this up for commercial, non-personal uses, remember to review the license requirements, as that may change which of the above options is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score -1):

there is a way, first you have to download an ubuntu oficial image in dockerhub and then something like this docker run -d -v C:/Users/francis.delacruz/Projects:/mnt/test ubuntu /bin/bash, in your windows desktop continue doing your makefile because you will execute in your linux container even you could deploy all in this terminal bash just you nedd to install all dependecies finally just test. when you put this -v in the container it will mount windows desktop memory into the ubuntu container so its like a mixture. i hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: Please don't post text walls.